# Make blank rows in a *ngFor loop

Tags: angular

I am trying to make about 10 blank rows so will be symmetric the the `<div>` next to it.

Right now I have:

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let officeInfo of officeInformation">
        <td>{{officeInfo.supervisorOffice}}</td>
        <td>{{officeInfo.office}}</td>
        <td>{{officeInfo.command}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
```

I have tried

```
<tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let officeInfo of officeInformation + 10">
            <td>{{officeInfo.supervisorOffice}}</td>
            <td>{{officeInfo.office}}</td>
            <td>{{officeInfo.command}}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
```

and that did not work. There cannot find any doc's on how to achieve it.

------------------------------UPDATE 1----------------------------

It has been brought to my attention that I should use `@Pipe`

I am doing it like so:

import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from "@angular/core";

```
@Pipe({ name: 'emptyArray' })
export class EmptyArrayPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value, size: number) {
        return new Array(size).fill(0);
    }
}
```

Then in my loop I add it:

```
<tr *ngFor="let officeInfo of officeInformation | emptyArray:10">
            <td>{{officeInfo.supervisorOffice}}</td>
            <td>{{officeInfo.office}}</td>
            <td>{{officeInfo.command}}</td>
        </tr>
```

However now it just prints out an empty table.

Comment: What is `+10` supposed to do? `officeInformation` is hardly an integer otherwise `officeInfo.superviosorOffice` wouldn't make sense.

Comment: What's `{{officeInfo.supervisorOffice}}` for in the blank rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let officeInfo of officeInformation + 10">
        <td>{{officeInfo.supervisorOffice}}</td>
        <td>{{officeInfo.office}}</td>
        <td>{{officeInfo.command}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let dummy of empty">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
```

```
class MyComponent {
  empty = new Array(10).fill(null);
}
```

**update**

This way the rows will be filled so that there are always 10 rows even when `officeInformation` contains less items:

```
@Pipe({name: 'fillRows'}) 
export class FillRowsPipe{ 
  transform(value, size: number) { 
    if(!value || !size) {
      size = 10;
    }
    var missing = size - (value ? value.length : 0);
    if(missing < 0) {
      return null;
    }
    return new Array(missing).fill(null); 
  }
}
```

```
<tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let officeInfo of officeInformation + 10">
        <td>{{officeInfo.supervisorOffice}}</td>
        <td>{{officeInfo.office}}</td>
        <td>{{officeInfo.command}}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let dummy of officeInformation|fillRows:10">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Great idea, I just also need to put data into the null rows when necessary. I will say this is the correct answer but it has a time limit.

Comment: If you need this at different places, you can create a pipe that takes a size parameter and returns an array like `<tr *ngFor="let dummy of null | emptyArray:10">` with `@Pipe({name: 'emptyArray'}) class EmptyArrayPipe{ transform(value, size: number) { return new Array(size).fill(null); }`

Comment: All that did was give me 10 row of null (empty) columns. Witht he `@Pipe`
See update

Comment: What do you want instead?

Comment: It renders everything that is in `officeInformation` but if the table is not 10 rows long make them null. If the user inputs a value the null row is now filled with that value.

Comment: "but if the table is not 10 rows long make them null" Not sure what that means. You always want 10 rows, and if the data is less, fill it with blank rows? " If the user inputs a value the null row is now filled with that value" Does this mean there should be one blank row less in case the user adds a new entry?

Comment: The only issue now is ` transform(value, size: number) { 
    if(!value || !number) {` is not working. `size: number` cannot be found

Comment: Sorry, there is a mistake. it should be `if(!value || !size) {`. (https://plnkr.co/edit/dDUEdp7PMv7bYxph2NjS?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to add some empty Objects to the `officeInformation` array. I would recommend using a getter that adds new empty rows:

```
class MyController {
  retrieveOfficeInformation() {
    this.officeInformation = // data for the office
    // before adding more empty rows, check if the last row has any data
    if (this.officeInformation[this.officeInformation.length - 1].id) {
      this.officeInformation = this.officeInformation.concat([
        // empty objects go here
        {},
        {}
      ]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I also need to put data into the null rows when necessary not create new ones unless all the rows are used than it will scroll.

Comment: @Drew1208 updated to take that into account, you will need to replace the conditional for `.id` with some other field name that makes sense (or a function that checks whether that object in the array is empty)