# How to add blank cells in an HTML table so row has the same amount of cells as a row with data?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have an HTML table which has the data imported into it using *ngFor. Some of the rows in the table has 12 pieces of data so it has 12 columns, but some rows only have 2 pieces of data so only has 2 columns.

I have tried to use empty-cells: show in CSS, but because the extra cells I want to show don't have any data, they don't show.

I also tried to add in the extra empty `<td>` elements, but then because I am using `*ngFor` it also adds the empty cells onto the end of every row, so they are still uneven.

I have made a basic [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-igf91a?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css), to demonstrate the issue. In the example I want to be able to have a grey background on all of the cells even if they have no data.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: please post your ngfor. We need to add empty td dynamically to solve this problem

Comment: @Irin I have updated the StackBlitz now

Comment: As I already commented yesterday on the version of this question you deleted by now - I think modifying your input data, so that each “line” in there contains the right amount of columns to begin with, would probably be the easiest way to solve this. `array = ["info,info,info,info","info,info,,","info,info,info,"]` would get you the same amount of cells in all rows. (It gets you an additional fifth empty cell on each row in the current version of your code - but that seems to be a separate issue, because that was the case already for the first row in your given example.)

Comment: I have add the solution check it out @Dirtz

Answer (score 1):

You can have it using `colspan` and `rowspan` for columns and rows:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">65</th>
        <th colspan="2">40</th>
        <th colspan="2">20</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th>Men</th>
        <th>Women</th>
        <th>Men</th>
        <th>Women</th>
        <th>Men</th>
        <th>Women</th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

More details here: https://html.com/tables/rowspan-colspan/

You also can avoid the usage of tables and create the whole layout with DIVs and grid or Flexbox.

To learn more about CSS Grid: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/

To learn more about CSS Flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Example with empty cells: https://codepen.io/fabiozanchi/pen/QXrPbV

Comment: This does not achieve the desired result. I am still left with cells that have no background colour as they have no data.

Comment: some `td` tags are missing, that's why nothing appears. I have updated my answer with your code showing the empty cells.

Comment: Adding in empty `<td>` cells won't work in my case as I am using `*ngFor` for the data in each row, so i do not know the amount of data in each row so cannot add in the right amount of empty `<td>` elements.

Comment: Got it. Perhaps you can find your answer in this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42932664/make-blank-rows-in-a-ngfor-loop

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be what you are trying to do

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
    <th colspan="2">65</th>
    <th colspan="2">40</th>
    <th colspan="2">20</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Men</th>
    <th>Women</th>
    <th>Men</th>
    <th>Women</th>
    <th>Men</th>
    <th>Women</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Men 1</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th>Women1</th>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th>Women2</th>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your table with the following code. this will work perfectly.

```
<table id="table">
 <tr>
   <td *ngFor = "let col of tableColumns">{{col}}</td>
 </tr>
 <tr *ngFor = "let data of array">
   <td *ngFor = "let col of tableColumns; index as i">{{data.split(',')[i]}}</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

add the header row with this array

```
tableColumns = ['HEADER1', 'HEADER2', 'HEADER3', 'HEADER4'];
```